# Error while running behave_main from windows

Tags: python, bdd, python-behave

**What i am trying**
I am trying to run behave from a Window machine which don't have behave or any other depended libraries pip installed.
1. Including all modules path to sys.path.
2. Running behave using behave_main method.

**Code sample:**

```
import sys
sys.path.append('C:\\MyWorkspace\\synthetics\\features\\modules\\behave-1.2.6')
sys.path.append('C:\\MyWorkspace\\synthetics\\features\\modules\\parse-1.8.4')
sys.path.append('C:\\MyWorkspace\\synthetics\\features\\modules\\selenium-3.13.0')
sys.path.append('C:\\MyWorkspace\\synthetics\\features\\modules\\parse_type-0.4.2')
sys.path.append('C:\\MyWorkspace\\synthetics\\features\\modules\\traceback2-1.4.0')
sys.path.append('C:\\MyWorkspace\\synthetics\\features\\modules\\linecache2-1.0.0')
sys.path.append('C:\\MyWorkspace\\synthetics\\features\\modules\\nose-1.3.7')
sys.path.append('C:\\MyWorkspace\\synthetics\\features\\modules\\six-1.11.0')
sys.path.append('C:\\MyWorkspace\\synthetics\\features\\modules\\enum-0.4.6')

from behave.__main__ import main as behave_main
behave_main(["C:\\MyWorkspace\\synthetics\\features\\", "-n Login"])
```

I am able to run behave script this way from my Mac OS, having issue doing the same from Windows machine.

**Error:**

```
C:\MyWorkspace\synthetics\features>python run_behave.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run_behave.py", line 16, in <module>
    behave_main(["C:\\MyWorkspace\\synthetics\\features\\", "-n NEAT"])
  File "C:\MyWorkspace\synthetics\features\modules\behave-1.2.6\behave\__main__.py", line 182, in main
    config = Configuration(args)
  File "C:\MyWorkspace\synthetics\features\modules\behave-1.2.6\behave\configuration.py", line 647, in __init__
    self.reporters.append(SummaryReporter(self))
  File "C:\MyWorkspace\synthetics\features\modules\behave-1.2.6\behave\reporter\summary.py", line 49, in __init__
    self.feature_summary = {Status.passed.name: 0, Status.failed.name: 0,
AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'name'
```

**Update**
I was able to eliminate this issue by running the code with Behave 1.2.5. This issue exists in 1.2.6 version.

Comment: Could you check the installed versions of `Python` and `behave` on both systems?

Comment: Python 2.7 version on both systems and I am trying to run behave in both systems without PIP installing the same. Above steps worked for me in Mac.

Comment: You're using the `-n` flag. In the first snippet you're matching against feature files with "Login"; in the second snippet you're matching against feature files with "Neat".  Try having a simple feature file and test step to test this with

Comment: **I was able to eliminate this issue by running the code with Behave 1.2.5**. This issue exists in 1.2.6 version.